# Admin users not able to see network menus

Tags: multisite, admin, user-roles, network-admin

I am new to wordpress, and I am an admin in my site. But I can't see the network menu, SuperAdmins can.

[image]

Any idea why? I am using the user role editor plugin to manage roles. But I haven;t changed any permission for Administrator roles.

Answer (score 0):

On a multisite, the 'super-admin' is the only one that gets to see the 'master' site.

Admins can see their individual sub-sites. The super-admin can admin all the sub-sites.

Comment: Oh, Only super admin can access network-admin pages? @rick-hellewell

Comment: On a multisite, the SuperAdmin is the admin user that created the site (usually). Also allowed to create sub-sites. Subsites have their own admin for their own subsite. You can add, as a SuperAdmin, other SuperAdmins to the main/master site.